# Enable last div of same class

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I am making an ajax call to get more results and get them appended to the existing ones in the same page. While the contents are fetched, i need to show a scrolling spinner every time  requests are send. In order to achieve this i go on adding a div at bottom of results fetched like this:

```
<div class="loader" style="display:block"></div>
```

And i am trying to show the spinner using the below code:

```
beforeSend: function() 
{
      $('#loader:last-child').html('<img src="/graphics/loading.gif" alt="Wait" />');
}
complete: function()
{
      $('#loader:last-child').html('');
}
```

But i am not able to get the spinner effect, it is not at all shown on the page(results are though fetched).

Please help me in getting it corrected. Any other thoughts to have the spinner effect are also appreciated.

EDIT: I have removed quotes as they wre in my perl code. sorry for that.

Comment: Why are the quotes escaped in your code?

Comment: The quotes are escaped as the code is in perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding any new elements or images, you could just add a class to the container of your results while it's loading, and use the class to add padding and the spinner graphic as the background image of the container. When the loading completes, remove the class:

```
beforeSend: function(){
    $('#resultsContainer').addClass('loading');
}
complete: function(){
    $('#resultsContainer').removeClass('loading');
}
```

Then your CSS could look like:

```
#resultsContainer.loading {
    background: url(graphics/loading.gif) no-repeat center bottom;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

For extra style, add transitions to padding-bottom on resultContainer, so that the loading graphic slides smoothly in and out.

Comment: I already have one class with the results container, i added your code, but i don't see the spinner.

Comment: I got it working, also as per my requirement, i have made it left(spinner) and padding bottom to 4em. Looks perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Put a space in `<imgsrc` so that its `<img src`

Your selector should be `$('.loader:last-child')` since loader is a class not an id. (Use `.` instead of `#`)

Comment: Its working :) but with problems
1) The spinner not show for first ajax request, for request made after first its visible
2) The spinner does not hide after results are shown, so the complete thing in ajax is not working.

Comment: @ kailash19: It is great, now add a comma `,` after `beforeSend: function(){},` and try; Hopefulley it will work.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using `\` slashes

try this

```
beforeSend: function() 
{
      $('.loader:last-child').html('<img src="/graphics/loading.gif" alt="Wait" />');
}
complete: function()
{
      $('.loader:last-child').html('');
}
```

Comment: I have removed quotes(they were there as code is called from perl script), still not working

Comment: have you checked your image path?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
beforeSend: function() 
{
      $("#loader").last().html('<img src="/graphics/loading.gif" alt="Wait" />');
}
complete: function()
{
      $("#loader").last().html('');
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'last'

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to escape the quotes, also put a `space` between `imgsrc` like `img src`

As well mentioned by **rob** in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275121/1516616) that

> Your selector should be **$('.loader:last-child')** since loader is a class not an id. Use pereiod **(.)** instead of **(#)**

Also add a comma `,` after `beforeSend: function(){},` and try;

**Use the following code:**

```
beforeSend: function() {
    $('.loader:last-child').html('<img src="/graphics/loading.gif" alt="Wait" />');
},

complete: function() {
      $('.loader:last-child').html('');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the quotes were in my perl code, i have edited my post.
Added space too in img src, its still not working

Comment: hmmm did you checked the image path?

Comment: @kailash19: try to add comma `,` after `beforeSend: function(){},`

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the loader image to the HTML of e #loader and then remove it.
(note that I added an id to the image)

```
beforeSend: function() 
{
      $('.loader').append('<img src="/graphics/loading.gif" id="waitSpinner" alt="Wait" />');
}
complete: function()
{
      $('#waitSpinner').remove();
}
```

Edit: changed #loader to .loader, as that was the class.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code as you mention, it was not working, then i changed it to:
$('.loader')(. in place of #). It works but just for the first request(i see 2 spinners now :P), for requests after that, i do see the spinner but they are not hidden or go away once results are fetched, also the number of spinner i see gets multiplied by 2(is it due to that append).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Edited it. Anyways, glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `.` for selecting class not `#` its for id and also `,` is missing between beforeComplete and complete.

Comment: added . but facing these problems:
1) The spinner not show for first ajax request, for request made after first its visible 2) The spinner does not hide after results are shown, so the complete thing in ajax is not working